# fun - part of speech

Tags: parts-of-speech

Compared to other languages, English is in practice pretty indifferent with regards to parts of speech. The lines are often blurry. 
I'm curious about the following phrase:

> It's fun.

Usually, I'd think that "fun" is a noun. For instance I can have lots of it. However, there are phrasings where it is used much like a qualifier.

> It was a fun ride.

Just looking at the structure, it could be either an adjective or a noun in the phrase in question.

> It's fun/milk.
>   It's fun/nice.

My first impulse was "noun" but seeing how there is no article and how most phrasings that express roughly the same would use an adjective, I am not so sure anymore.
Here are my questions.

- What part of speech is "fun" in the phrase?
- Do native speakers clearly perceive it as noun or adjective respectively or would both readings make sense on an intuition level?

Comment: It can actually be seen as both, since we don't change the linking verb between predicate nouns and adjectives. Fun is both a noun and an adjective. I as a native speaker do not think "noun" or "adjective" when saying this sentence or others like it; I just think "fun" and intuitively understand it to mean "fun".

Comment: To elaborate on "seeing how there is no article", not all nouns need articles. Plural nouns don't necessarily need an article: "I see cats" and neither do uncountable nouns. Fun is an uncountable noun, like water: "I drink water."

Comment: I remember hearing somewhere that "fun" used to only be a noun, but many people nowadays use it as an adjective as well. Its originally being a noun supposedly explains the non-standard nature of *funner, *funnest.

Comment: Intuititively I think of _fun_ as an adjective in _It's fun_, analogous to _It's nice_, but it can also be a noun in _We're going to have fun_.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fun&searchmode=none The etymology implies that both the adjectival use and the noun use arose from the OE verb *fonnen*. The adjectival has older attestation, but that doesn't always prove source. It is becoming obsolete, but fun is still occasionally used as a verb as tchrist alluded to in another comment. I agree with ScotM that flexibility is the more accurate perception of the native speaker when it comes to parts of speech. It drives the analytic types crazy, that we don't feel compelled to *draw inside the lines* :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Indifferent* is not the correct word to describe the way native English speakers regard parts of speech; it's more like ***flexible***:

In the unambiguous expression:

> *the children enjoyed the **fun** and games*

*Fun* **is** a noun.

In the unambiguous expression:

> *the children enjoyed the **fun** games*

*Fun* **is** an adjective.

In the ambiguous expression:

> *it's fun*

The larger context will determine the part of speech:

> *Fun* is renaming *it* as a predicate **noun**.
>
> **or**
>
> Fun is describing *it* as a predicate **adjective**.

As long as people can perceive, use and interpret parts of speech properly, it is not **so** important to label them. We teach our children to label parts of speech so that they can ***learn*** to speak, read and write properly. As instructors, the labels remain supremely relevant to us, but once our students can speak, read and write, the labels quickly become **less** relevant to them. Those who **never** discuss parts of speech, tend to forget the significance of the labels, because they don't need the labels to communicate.

Comment: It almost doesn't make a difference in the ambiguous case. Fun and games are fun games.

Comment: I agree! The noun *fun* and the adjective *fun* are so conceptually connected that it borders on irrelevance, but the larger context may indicate that one is preferable over the other.

Comment: I used "indifferent" because I find that many English speakers have no idea what part of speech their dealing with. It doesn't seem to matter to them whether something is a verb or a noun. I have been a German teacher for more than 5 years and I'm always surprised about this. But given the flexibility it does make sense.

Comment: @Eman "Part of speech" is merely a madey-uppy classification scheme dreamt up to try to describe  what words are doing. It is imperfect and approximate at best, with holes and paradoxes like any other formal system. Native speakers couldn't care less because such labels DO NOT MATTER to them, nor should they. They know how to use words correctly without needing to know which of the coupla dozen parts of speech somebody decided those words "are".

Comment: @tchrist... well, I cannot fully agree because not knowing whether the "ban" you're looking at is a noun or a verb will make it impossible for you to find the right word in another language because English is very special in it's flexibility. In most languages you'll have two distinct words for that. And "ban" is not the only example. There are hundred of those. If you use the noun where you should have used the verb you'll most likely not be understood. Just imagine I was to say "During I was in school"... it's wrong. Knowing what a preposition and a conjunction would have prevented that.

Comment: Perlen vor die Säue?

Comment: @Emanuel Again, that doesn't matter to a native speaker; it's just a translator's problem. And even there, the putative part of speech is much less important than the actual meaning of the word. For example I can tell you to look up *ban* as a noun, and you still will not know what I am talking about, particularly considering that I was talking about the governors or viceroys of certain military districts in Hungary, Slavonia, and Croatia who take command during times of war, and when I chose to *ban* someone, they become a *ban* temporarily. See the problem? Parts of speech don't matter much.

Comment: Perlas a los cerdos!

Comment: @tchrist... no I actually don't see it. I see it in class though. It's correct that it doesn't matter for a native speaker but reducing it to a problem of a translator does ignore the very fact that there are languages that clearly mark which is which and that are very strict about the distinction. Anyway, we've both made our points and we clearly won't agree with each other so let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @ScotM Aunque el cochinillo se vista con perlas para mejor hacerse bolsa de seda, cochinillo no-volante se queda.

Comment: Now you’re just funnin’ with ’em. :)

Comment: Vueltas y vueltas va. Donde se deja de nadie sabe!

Comment: @tchrist, the add on at the end was actually in response to the second part of the question: *Do native speakers clearly perceive it as noun or adjective respectively or would both readings make sense on an intuition level?*

Comment: You say that in "*the children enjoyed the fun games*" ***fun*** is unambiguously an adjective.  And yet many speakers (including me (English)) find the comparative forms strange "*the games they played yesterday were funner*"...

Answer (score 3):

The adverb "very" can modify adjectives, so if "fun" in "It's fun" were an adjective, you would be able to say *"It's very fun."  But you can't (at least, not in my opinion).  That would have to be expressed as "It's a lot of fun", which has "fun" as object of a preposition and so a noun.  So, I think the "fun" you asked about is a noun and not an adjective.

Elsewhere, "fun" is an adjective and can be modified by "very": "The carousel is a very fun ride", where "ride" is a noun modified by the adjective "fun" and "fun" is modified by "very".

Comment: Very good point. Google Ngram shows very few hits for _very fun_, many for _a lot of fun_.

Comment: What do you think of Uno? It's fun! It's quite fun. It's uproariously fun! It's exceedingly fun!

Comment: Uh, Arduino Uno?

Comment: *Fun* didn't use to be an adjective. The original 1828 Webster's dictionary has "FUN, *noun* Sport; vulgar merriment. A low word." The first Webster's International (1892) has "fun, *n.* Sport; merriment." This is probably why we say *more fun* and not *funner*, and why *"it's very fun"* sounds wrong.

Comment: I believe ScotM refers to the card came Uno. I *fun* you not, it's loads of *fun* for *fun* people! The adverbial argument has some merit, but the flexibility of fun seems to eat it alive.

Comment: "*The carousel is a very fun ride, but the big wheel is funner*"...?

Comment: @Dan, The comparative of "fun" is "more fun".

Comment: @GregLee - are there many single syllable adjectives that use 'more' for the comparative rather than the usual '-er'?

Comment: @Dan – There are several monosyllabic adjectives whose comparative and superlative forms forgo the conventional endings — *fun* is, of course, one of them. Other notable examples include *real*, *loath*, *ill*, *worth*, and *just*.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns can be used as compound elements for compound nouns as in fruit tree, oil well etc. If it comes to describing compound nouns consisting of two nouns I would not use the term adjective for the first noun. This is a confusion of terms. There should be special terms for word classes, word groups, sentence structures and word composition. If one term is used in several categories this is unclear terminology.

Comment: Good point! It would be perfectly acceptable to analyze fun games as a compound noun, but the persistent use of that construction in multiple compounds eventually gives rise to an adjectival designation!

Comment: Compound nouns are dictionary entries. At least you find them in larger dictionaries. A combination of an adjective and a noun is normally not registered in dictionaries. With the exception of cases where adjective + noun are a fixed expression as red herring. But if a compond noun is decribed as adjective + noun it is totally unclear what is meant. The first compound element may be a normal adjective as in red herring or it may be a noun as in herring gull. And I think such differences should be described with clear terms.

Comment: Confusion of labels. Finding *fun* in a dictionary as an adjective, noun **and** verb is unsatisfactory? Sounds like you are proposing to scrap the status quo and reorganize our study of the English language. Sounds like an interesting dissertation :-)

Comment: There are dictionaries or grammars which have special terms such as combining form.

Comment: I've just found a pair like heavyweight and a heavy weight. It would not be appropriate to say heavy is an adjective in both cases. Actually that explains nothing and you don't see what is meant.